# How do I add image tag in fpdf

Tags: php, html, fpdf

```
$message ='<img src="new_star.png" style="height:10px;width:10px">'; 
$pdf->writeHTML($message);
$pdf->Output();
```

How can i use this code to display image in pdf

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the code that you posted. Instead use the `image` option provided by fPDF to include an image in your document. Use the full path to the image unless the image is in the directory where your script is running.

The prototype from the documentation is:

`Image(string file [, float x [, float y [, float w [, float h [, string type [, mixed link]]]]]])`

Details on the options may be found in the documentation available at http://www.fpdf.org/.

Comment: @khairuddeen this is what I have answered.

Comment: _i want use this image tag $message ='<img src="new_star.png" style="height:10px;width:10px">'; but not disply image i want this type of code not like that your code_ this is what you are saying @khairuddeen.

Comment: yes i saying i want  $message ='<img src="new_star.png" style="height:10px;width:10px">'; this code but i didnt get that answer so i just thank

Comment: You can not use a HTML img tag to include an image in fPDF. You would have to use the fPDF image tag.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can add image in pdf using `fpdf`

```
$pdf->Image('file link',x-position,y-position,width,height);
```

`File link` is the link to your image and `x & y position` is where image is located. `width and height` are width and height of image.
You can also take a look at fpdf documentation. [Documentation for images](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/image.htm)

Comment: i  want to use image tag

Comment: please be clear, do you want to add the image or it's tag for something like documentation

Comment: i want use this image tag                                                                                                   $message ='<img src="new_star.png" style="height:10px;width:10px">';  but not disply image i want this type of code not like that your code

Comment: i didnt do it that

Comment: what? okay my answer, answers your question just add your image link to file link and its position and width and height